# How can slot_nb_bool(slot function for __bool__) call __len__?

Tags: python, cpython

Python-3.5.1\Objects\typeobject.c

```
UNSLOT("__bool__", nb_bool, slot_nb_bool, wrap_inquirypred,
       "self != 0"),


static int
slot_nb_bool(PyObject *self)
{
    PyObject *func, *args;
    int result = -1;
    int using_len = 0;
    _Py_IDENTIFIER(__bool__);

    func = lookup_maybe(self, &PyId___bool__);
    if (func == NULL) {
        if (PyErr_Occurred())
            return -1;
        func = lookup_maybe(self, &PyId___len__);
        if (func == NULL)
            return PyErr_Occurred() ? -1 : 1;
        using_len = 1;
    }
...
```

In my view, slot function is used only when **__bool__** is defined in python source as follows:

```
def __bool__(self):
    return True
```

if `func = lookup_maybe(self, &PyId___bool__);` return NULL, it indicates no `__bool__` is defined. Then slot will not be filled with slot_nb_bool. slot_nb_bool will not be called.

How can slot_nb_bool(slot function for `__bool__`) call `__len__`?

Answer (score 0):

If **bool** is defined, `lookup_maybe(self, &PyId___bool__);` will return something, and it will be used. If **bool** is not defined, it will return NULL, and there'll be attempt to use **len** instead.

Comment: if bool is not defined, nb_bool should be NULL, slot_nb_bool will not be called.